# ViewController does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource

Tags: swift, swift3

**Where's the wrong?

ERROR "SecondViewController does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource"**

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

{

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var videos:[video] = [video]()

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


        let model = videoModel()
        self.videos = videoModel().getVideos()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

    }

func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell", for: indexPath)

        let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row].videoTitle

        //customize the cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = videoTitle


    return cell

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image. Copy and paste the actual, relevant code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, You did not connect UIViewController and UITableView.

In Stroyboard,
Place your mouse over UITableView, Drag to UIViewController using right button. And then you can check outlets options, datasource and delegate. Check these.